# How do I make an AC_CACHE_CHECK critical?

Tags: autotools, configure, autoconf

I perform some checks during configure, which i set up with autoconf using the AC_CACHE_CHECK macro. Some checks are critical, so if they donÄt pass, I want configure to fail. How can I achieve this?

Thanks, Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean.  Do you want to abort if the result is not cached?  Or, if the result is not cached, do you want to attempt to assign a value but abort if unsuccesful?  For the latter,  just do:

```
# Replace 3rd argument with commands to assign the cache variable
# See autoconf documentation for how to name the cache variable
AC_CACHE_CHECK([myvariable], [sss_cv_type_myvar], [sss_cv_type_myvar=yes])
myvariable=$sss_cv_type_myvar
AS_IF([test x"$myvariable" != xyes],[AC_MSG_ERROR(
    [myvariable not yes])])
```

If you want to abort merely because the variable is not cached, you could put an `exit` in the 3rd argument to `AC_CACHE_CHECK`.  The commands in that option are used to assign the cache variable, and are not supposed to have side effects.  Exiting the configure script is definitely a side effect, but that may be the behavior you want.